# firebase free hosting limits

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

When talking about the limits on the free firebase hosting plan, it says we have a free 1 GB stored and 10 GB/month transferred. Does this mean we have can have 1 GB currently hosted in our app, or does it include previous deployments?

For example, If I deploy 100MB, and then redeploy it later, it stores the last version in case you want to roll back. This is what I have done, and when I look at the usage tab is says I have 200 MB of storage.

Does this count towards the 1 GB limit? Or is it only the currently deployed version that counts? Do I need to be actively deleting past deployments to avoid reaching the 1 GB limit? Additionally, what happens when I reach that limit? Will it just refuse to deploy?

Answer (score 1):

Storage limits include all stored versions, not just the currently deployed one. When you reach that limit, you may be prevented from deploying.